# How to Give Assets Folder Path for Playing mp4 video?

Tags: android

How to Give Assets Folder Path for Playing mp4 video? I am Using Following Code for that.

Please Help me.

```
String stringPath = "file:///android_asset/sample.mp4";
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But Above Code is Give me Following Warnings & Errors.

```
07-25 13:11:40.833: ERROR/MediaPlayer(11295): error (1, -2147483648)
07-25 13:11:40.833: WARN/System.err(11295): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-25 13:11:41.103: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-25 13:11:41.103: WARN/System.err(11295):     at com.arthisoft.tempforvideo2.AndroidVideoPlayer.playvideo(AndroidVideoPlayer.java:69)
07-25 13:11:41.103: WARN/System.err(11295):     at com.arthisoft.tempforvideo2.AndroidVideoPlayer$2.onClick(AndroidVideoPlayer.java:52)
07-25 13:11:41.113: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-25 13:11:41.113: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-25 13:11:41.123: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-25 13:11:41.123: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 13:11:41.123: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 13:11:41.134: WARN/System.err(11295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 13:11:41.143: WARN/System.err(11295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 13:11:41.143: WARN/System.err(11295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 13:11:41.143: WARN/System.err(11295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 13:11:41.153: WARN/System.err(11295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 13:11:41.153: WARN/System.err(11295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 13:11:41.153: ERROR/MediaPlayer(11295): start called in state 0
07-25 13:11:41.163: ERROR/MediaPlayer(11295): error (-38, 0)
07-25 13:11:41.243: ERROR/MediaPlayer(11295): Error (-38,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the .mp4 file to `raw/` folder. Then, replace your string with this:

```
String stringPath = "android.resource://[your_package_name]/raw/sample"
```

Comment: Try this: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(stringPath))` instead of your 4th line

Comment: `this` is a reference to your context AND the `stringPath` is the one I wrote above.

Comment: Update the question with these two lines from your code: `tempforvideo2.playvideo(line:6)` AND `tempforvideo2.onClick(line:52)`. The error seems to occur in these two.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify your location is in the sd card or in the internal storage. If it is in the sd card then it will be:

```
String stringPath = "/sdcard/android_asset/sample.mp4";
```

Comment: I used only Internal Storage(Assets Folder)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AndroidVideoPlayer.this, Uri
        .parse("android.resource://com.arthisoft.tempforvideo2/R.raw.sample"));
```

Comment: It depends on where your file is stored. You have to make a valid URI based on the file location. My answer was just an example of how to do so.

Comment: My File is Stored on Raw Folder in my Project. if i Copy the Files on SD Card then this is work otherwise don't work.