# Playing a mp4 video with from the res/raw folder via phonegap videoplayer-plugin

Tags: android, video, cordova, playback, phonegap-plugins

im trying to play a video from the raw folder with phonegap.
I modified the original plugin a little bit.
this is the code:

```
       Uri uri = Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+R.raw.test);
    // Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.test.sociato.de/test.mp4");

    Intent intent = null;
        // Display video player
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

    this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

The video is in the raw folder and is named test.mp4.
The code doesnt work.

I think that the url to the video isnt correct?
I would be very pleased of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you can't play video from application's private package to default video player,Because your default video player can't recognize this path.**

To make it play you have to `copy this video file in sdcard` and then give URI of that file, in this case it works fine.

Comment: thanks very much.
i've read this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813069/how-to-give-assets-folder-path-for-playing-mp4-video
there you can play the video from the res folder, dont you?

Comment: In that link they implement videoview, not playing on default player of device.

Answer (score 2):

I wrestled with this one for awhile.  The only way I could play a video from an Android resource was to copy it first to the sdcard.  Here's my code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myfolder");
if(dir.isDirectory() != true) {
dir.mkdirs();

InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myvid);
int size = ins.available();
// Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
ins.read(buffer);
ins.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, "myvid.m4v"));
fos.write(buffer);
fos.close(); 
}

File myvid = new File(dir, "myvid.m4v");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myvid), "video/*");  
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully played a video file that I loaded into the res/raw folder directly from that resource.

This was done in

Android 1.5

API Level 3

The file size was below 50M

My code snippet is as follows

```
        Uri video= Uri.parse("android.resource://MYPACKAGENAME/" + R.raw.presence); 
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
```

The main issue I saw occurring was getting App to recognize the mp4 file in the raw folder

I am new to android development but this is what I did I hope it helps.

In the first line as I typed "R.raw" Eclipse showed it as an error I typed the period and expected Eclipse to show me a quick list of the resources but it was not there.

I read in another post to do a clean on the project and the resource list would be refreshed when I clicked PROJECT - CLEAN the resource was identified.

Another thing that I believe is required is that the file name MUST be lowercase only.
When it was in mixed case it would not show up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This code from above:

```
Uri video= Uri.parse("android.resource://MYPACKAGENAME/" + R.raw.presence); 
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

worked great for me!

MYPACKAGENAME = full package name to work.  I got stuck here for minute.